# Trigger click event on a Google Maps KML placemark

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a map that is loading in dynamic external KML with placemarks defined like so:

```
<Placemark id="MapZoneID_23443">
    <name>Name Here</name>
    <description>Text Here</description>
    <styleUrl>#ff8080ff</styleUrl>
    <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                    ....
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

What I'd like to do is have a link / dropdown / whatever that can be clicked or selected to basically trigger a click on `$('#MapZoneID_23443')` ... but I can't figure out how to trigger that click or if this is even possible. The maps can be quite complex, so I would prefer to not have to preload everything using JS gmaps markers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible.

Star the issue on the bug tracker to both vote for it and follow it's progress: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3006

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround.

Add this to your placemark in the `<style>` section

```
<BalloonStyle><text>TEXT</text></BalloonStyle>
```

You will be able to access this value after click in .js callback as

```
event.featureData.info_window_html
```

So, in your KML file

```
<Placemark id="MapZoneID_23443">
   <BalloonStyle><text>TEXT</text></BalloonStyle>
   ...
</Placemark>
```

And in javascript

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(event) {
  var content = event.featureData.info_window_html;
  console.log(content);
});
```